# Why is MPI_Allgatherv not gathering to all?

Tags: c++, mpi

I've written an parallel Jacobi algorithm which solves sparses linear systems. All the non zero coefficients of the matrix have been stored in a modified CRS form inside a vector, the first element of each row is the diagonal element. Here's the main routine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;
using double_vector = vector<double>;
using int_vector = vector<int>;

int main() {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int WorldRank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &WorldRank);
    int WorldSize;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &WorldSize);

    int Order = 8;
    int Length = 22;
    double_vector Coefficients(Length);
    int_vector RowIndex(Order+1);
    int_vector ColumnIndex(Length);
    double_vector InitialAnswer(Order);
    double_vector IndependentTerm(Order);   

    if (WorldRank == 0) {
        Coefficients = {10, 1, 10, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 10, 1};
        RowIndex = {0, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 22};
        ColumnIndex = {0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6};
        IndependentTerm = {11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11};
        InitialAnswer = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};
    }

    auto Start = steady_clock::now();
    double_vector Answer = Jacobi(Coefficients, RowIndex, ColumnIndex, IndependentTerm, InitialAnswer);

    if (WorldRank == 0) {
        auto End = steady_clock::now();
        duration<double> ElapsedSeconds = End - Start;
        print_vector(Answer, "Answer");
        cout << "\n\tElapsed time: " << setprecision(6) << ElapsedSeconds.count() << "s" << endl << endl;       
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the Jacobi routine:

```
double_vector Jacobi(double_vector& Coefficients, int_vector& RowIndex, int_vector& ColumnIndex, double_vector& IndependentTerm, double_vector& InitialAnswer) {
    int WorldRank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &WorldRank);
    int WorldSize;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &WorldSize);

    int Length = Coefficients.size();
    int Order = IndependentTerm.size();
    int Remainder = Order % WorldSize;
    int Counter = 0;
    int* Displacements = new int[WorldSize];
    int* ElementsPerProcess = new int[WorldSize];
    for (int i=0; i<WorldSize; i++) {
        ElementsPerProcess[i] = Order/WorldSize;
        if (Remainder > 0) {
            ElementsPerProcess[i]++;
            Remainder--;
        }
        Displacements[i] = Counter;
        Counter += ElementsPerProcess[i];
    }
    int iStart = Displacements[WorldRank];
    int iEnd = iStart + ElementsPerProcess[WorldRank];

    MPI_Bcast(&Coefficients[0], Length, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&RowIndex[0], Order+1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&ColumnIndex[0], Length, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&IndependentTerm[0], Order, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&InitialAnswer[0], Order, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int MaximumIterations = 1000;
    double Summatory;
    double_vector Answer(Order);
    for (int k=0; k<MaximumIterations; k++) {
        for (int i=iStart; i<iEnd; i++) {
            Summatory = 0.0;
            for (int j=RowIndex[i]+1; j<RowIndex[i+1]; j++) {
                Summatory -= Coefficients[j] * InitialAnswer[ColumnIndex[j]];
            }
            Summatory += IndependentTerm[i];
            Answer[i] = Summatory / Coefficients[RowIndex[i]];
        }
        MPI_Allgatherv(&Answer[iStart], ElementsPerProcess[WorldRank], MPI_DOUBLE, &InitialAnswer[0], ElementsPerProcess, Displacements, MPI_DOUBLE,    MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    delete Displacements;
    delete ElementsPerProcess;

    return Answer;
}
```

My test case is a 8x8 tridiagonal linear system with strictly dominant diagonal. The unknown values are all 1.0. Running **mpirun -n 1 ./main**, it prints the correct answer:

```
1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
```

However, when I execute this routine with more than one process the answer values are NOT gather to all process. That is, if **process 0** prints the answer, it shows the following:

```
1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
```

And if I get **process 1** to print the answer:

```
0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
```

It has been confirmed that all processes have properly access to the data I've broadcast. I also believe that I'm correctly using **MPI_Allgatherv**.

MPICH 3.2 - compiler: mpicxx - current flags: -g -std=c++14

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Results are gathered in `InitialAnswer`, not in `Answer`. Therefore the return values differ as each rank works on a different part of `Answer`.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you.